# cart total percentage discount in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, discount

I need to give 20% discount of cart total for all registered users in my store if the user register at the checkout time also get the benefit of discount. For guest checkout no need any discount

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps.

1. Navigate to Promotions > Shopping Cart Price Rules
2. Add New Rule
3. Rule Information Tab > Select Customer's Group
4. Actions Tab > Apply > Percent of product price discount
5. Actions Tab > Discount Amount > 20

Answer (score 0):

follow below step to give discount of 20%

1. open pramotion -> shoping cart price rule
2. add new rule
3. define rule name and all data select customer groped
4. in action define percentage